# Reduzir padding da UL durante scroll

Tags: css, css3

Como faço para **reduzir** o `padding` da `UL` `fixed` de `40px` para `20px` após rolar a tela em `10px` apenas usando CSS?

Tentei como abaixo mas **não** **funcionou**:

```css
  html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: content-box; /*Comprimir(diminuir) as medidas do elemento para não aumentá-lo quando adicinar margin e padding*/  
 }
   
 ul#menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 0; 
  border: .1px solid #000;
 }
 
 ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
 }
 
 @media screen and (min-height: 10px) {   
  ul#menu {
   padding: 20px 0;
  }
 }
```

```html
<ul id='menu'>
       <li>Menu 1</li><!--
 --><li>Menu 2</li><!--
 --><li>Menu 3</li><!--
 --><li>Menu 4</li><!--
 --><li>Menu 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Só com CSS não da pq CSS não detecta evento de scroll, mas se vc quiser uma resposta com JS puro ou jQuery, com 5 linhas de código vc resolve.

Comment: Com certeza quero sim! Quer dizer então que @media screen and (min-height: não existe? Dá uma versão com JS Puro e outra JQuery se não for pedir muito.

Comment: Claro que  `@media screen and (min-height:` vc tentou usa-lo para resolver seu problema? Acredito que vc nem tentou pq se tivesse tentado já teria visto que não da certo... Sobre o JS ou jQuery depende, vc já tem jQuery no projeto? Se já tem vai de jQuery, se não tem JS puro é melhor pq assim vc não precisa importa jQuery só pra isso

Comment: não tenho jQuery]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só com CSS você não consegue porque não tem como escutar o evento scroll com CSS. A media query que você está usando não calcula a posição do scroll, ela apenas verifica se a altura da janela é maior ou igual a `10px`.

Mas com JavaScript puro você consegue de forma fácil usando o evento `onscroll`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   
   window.onscroll = function(){
      var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
      menu.style.padding = (this.pageYOffset >= 10 ? 20 : 40) + "px 0";
   }
   
});
```

```css
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0; 
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: content-box; /*Comprimir(diminuir) as medidas do elemento para não aumentá-lo quando adicinar margin e padding*/  
}

ul#menu {
   position: fixed;
   width: 100vw;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 40px 0; 
   border: .1px solid #000;
}

ul#menu li {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 20%;
   height: 100px;
   line-height: 100px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul id='menu'>
       <li>Menu 1</li><!--
 --><li>Menu 2</li><!--
 --><li>Menu 3</li><!--
 --><li>Menu 4</li><!--
 --><li>Menu 5</li>
</ul>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```